# How do I add a dojo ComboBox to my DataGrid using a formatter?

Tags: checkbox, dojo, dojox.grid.datagrid, dijit.form

How do I add a dojo `ComboBox` to my `DataGrid` using a formatter? I thought from what I've been reading that I should be able to add a dojo `ComboBox` to my `DataGrid` with a `formatter` like I have done with my dojo `CheckBox` (and dojo `Button` on another html page I created). I cannot find a good example of this. I am using Dojo 1.10.0.

Here is my existing code which doesn't load because something is wrong with my `formatterCombobox` formatter:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
<title>Test Widget</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dojo-release-1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/dojomod.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo-release-1.10.0/dojo/resources/dojo.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dojo-release-1.10.0/dojox/grid/resources/claroGrid.css" />
    <script>dojoConfig = {async: true, parseOnLoad: false}</script>
    <script src="dojo-release-1.10.0/dojo/dojo.js"></script>

    <script>
require(['dojox/grid/DataGrid', 'dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore', 'dijit/form/CheckBox',  'dojo/domReady!'],
    function(DataGrid, ItemFileReadStore, CheckBox){
        function formatter(){
            var w = new CheckBox({
                label: "Use Input",
                onClick: function() {
                    alert("CheckBox - Checked! (or unchecked!)");
                }
            });
            w._destroyOnRemove=true;
            return w;

        function formatterCombobox(){
            var combobox = new ComboBox({
                label: "Combo",
                onClick: function() {
                    alert("CheckBox - Checked! (or unchecked!)");
                }
            });
            combobox._destroyOnRemove=true;
            return combobox;
        }

        }
        var layout = [
            {name: 'Feed', field: 'feed'},
            {name: 'Mission', field: 'mission', width: 6.5,
                styles: 'text-align: center; height: 21px;'},
            {name: 'Mission Override', field: 'missionoverride', width: 6.5,
                formatter: formatter,    /*Custom format, add a CheckBox. */
                styles: 'text-align: center;'
            },
            {name: 'OpMode', field: 'opmode', width: 6.5,
                styles: 'text-align: center; height: 21px;'},
            {name: 'OpMode Override', field: 'opmodeoverride', width: 6.5,
                formatter: formatter,    /*Custom format, add a CheckBox. */
                styles: 'text-align: center; height: 21px;'
            },
            {name: 'Platform', field: 'platform', width: 6.5,
                styles: 'text-align: center; height: 21px;'},
            {name: 'Tail Number', field: 'tailnumber', width: 6.5,
                styles: 'text-align: center; height: 21px;'
            },
            {name: 'Producer Org', field: 'producerorg', width: 6.5,
                styles: 'text-align: center; height: 21px;'
            },
        ];
        var store = new ItemFileReadStore({
            data: {
                identifier: "feed",
                items: [
                    {feed: '1. feed1', mission: 'mission1', override: '', mode: '', override: '', platform: '', number: '236', org: 'SA'},
                    {feed: '2. feed2', mission: 'mission2', override: '', mode: '', override: '', platform: '', number: '980', org: 'SA'},
                    {feed: '3. feed3', mission: 'mission3', override: '', mode: '', override: '', platform: '', number: '731', org: 'SA'},
                    {feed: '4. feed4', mission: 'mission4', override: '', mode: '', override: '', platform: '', number: '415', org: 'SA'},
                    {feed: '5. feed5', mission: 'mission5', override: '', mode: '', override: '', platform: '', number: '899', org: 'SA'},
                ]
            }
        });

        require([
                 "dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dojo/domReady!"
             ], function(Memory, ComboBox){
                 var stateStore = new Memory({
                     data: [
                         {name:"Alabama", id:"AL"},
                         {name:"Alaska", id:"AK"},
                         {name:"American Samoa", id:"AS"},
                         {name:"Arizona", id:"AZ"},
                         {name:"Arkansas", id:"AR"},
                         {name:"Armed Forces Europe", id:"AE"},
                         {name:"Armed Forces Pacific", id:"AP"},
                         {name:"Armed Forces the Americas", id:"AA"},
                         {name:"California", id:"CA"},
                         {name:"Colorado", id:"CO"},
                         {name:"Connecticut", id:"CT"},
                         {name:"Delaware", id:"DE"}
                     ]
                 });

                 var comboBox = new ComboBox({
                     id: "stateSelect",
                     name: "state",
                     value: "California",
                     store: stateStore,
                     searchAttr: "name"
                 }, "stateSelect").startup();
             });

        var grid = new DataGrid({
            id: 'grid',
            store: store,
            structure: layout,
            autoWidth: true,
            autoHeight: true
        });
        grid.placeAt('gridContainer');
        grid.startup();
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="claro">
    <div id="gridContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>

        require(['dojox/grid/DataGrid', 'dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore', 'dijit/form/CheckBox', "dijit/form/ComboBox",  'dojo/domReady!'],
                function (DataGrid, ItemFileReadStore, CheckBox, ComboBox) {
                    function formatter() {
                        var w = new CheckBox({
                            label: "Use Input",
                            onClick: function () {
                                alert("CheckBox - Checked! (or unchecked!)");
                            }
                        });
                        w._destroyOnRemove = true;
                        return w;

                    }

                    function formatterCombobox() {
                        var combobox = new ComboBox({
                            label: "Combo",
                            onClick: function () {
                                alert("CheckBox - Checked! (or unchecked!)");
                            }
                        });
                        combobox._destroyOnRemove = true;
                        return combobox;
                    }

                    var layout = [
                        {name: 'Feed', field: 'feed'},
                        {name: 'Mission', field: 'mission', width: 6.5,
                            styles: 'text-align: center; height: 21px;'},
                        {name: 'Mission Override', field: 'missionoverride', width: 6.5,
                            formatter: formatter, /*Custom format, add a CheckBox. */
                            styles: 'text-align: center;'
                        },
                        {name: 'OpMode', field: 'opmode', width: 6.5,
                            styles: 'text-align: center; height: 21px;'},
                        {name: 'OpMode Override', field: 'opmodeoverride', width: 6.5,
                            formatter: formatter, /*Custom format, add a CheckBox. */
                            styles: 'text-align: center; height: 21px;'
                        },
                        {name: 'Platform', field: 'platform', width: 6.5,
                            formatter: formatterCombobox,
                            styles: 'text-align: center; height: 21px;'},
                        {name: 'Tail Number', field: 'tailnumber', width: 6.5,
                            styles: 'text-align: center; height: 21px;'
                        },
                        {name: 'Producer Org', field: 'producerorg', width: 6.5,
                            formatter: formatterCombobox,
                            styles: 'text-align: center; height: 21px;'
                        },
                    ];
                    var store = new ItemFileReadStore({
                        data: {
                            identifier: "feed",
                            items: [
                                {feed: '1. feed1', mission: 'mission1', override: '', mode: '', override: '', platform: '', number: '236', org: 'SA'},
                                {feed: '2. feed2', mission: 'mission2', override: '', mode: '', override: '', platform: '', number: '980', org: 'SA'},
                                {feed: '3. feed3', mission: 'mission3', override: '', mode: '', override: '', platform: '', number: '731', org: 'SA'},
                                {feed: '4. feed4', mission: 'mission4', override: '', mode: '', override: '', platform: '', number: '415', org: 'SA'},
                                {feed: '5. feed5', mission: 'mission5', override: '', mode: '', override: '', platform: '', number: '899', org: 'SA'},
                            ]
                        }
                    });

                    require([
                        "dojo/store/Memory", "dijit/form/ComboBox", "dojo/domReady!"
                    ], function (Memory, ComboBox) {
                        var stateStore = new Memory({
                            data: [
                                {name: "Alabama", id: "AL"},
                                {name: "Alaska", id: "AK"},
                                {name: "American Samoa", id: "AS"},
                                {name: "Arizona", id: "AZ"},
                                {name: "Arkansas", id: "AR"},
                                {name: "Armed Forces Europe", id: "AE"},
                                {name: "Armed Forces Pacific", id: "AP"},
                                {name: "Armed Forces the Americas", id: "AA"},
                                {name: "California", id: "CA"},
                                {name: "Colorado", id: "CO"},
                                {name: "Connecticut", id: "CT"},
                                {name: "Delaware", id: "DE"}
                            ]
                        });

                        var comboBox = new ComboBox({
                            id: "stateSelect",
                            name: "state",
                            value: "California",
                            store: stateStore,
                            searchAttr: "name"
                        }, "stateSelect").startup();
                    });

                    var grid = new DataGrid({
                        id: 'grid',
                        store: store,
                        structure: layout,
                        autoWidth: true,
                        autoHeight: true
                    });
                    grid.placeAt('gridContainer');
                    grid.startup();
                });
    </script>
```

Comment: The solution fixes 3 issues, first the ComboBox constructor was not required in the first require statement. Second the formatterComboBox function was nested inside the formatter function now it is in the same scope as formatter.  Last, was that the formatterComboBox function was not being assigned to the appropriate formatter: property in the layout object.